# Creating 1D Array full of specified 1D arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

A rather simple question for most of you I suspect, although I can't seem to find the answer to it.

I have a function that takes in a 1D array and returns another array.

At the moment I am using a for loop to run this function many times, but I was suggested that I could increase my number of iterations if I was to create a function that would make a 1D array of a length equal to the number of iterations I want and then apply my function to this array.

For example:

```
inputs = np.array([23.,56,69])

def do_model(array):
    ... do magic ...
    return new_array
```

What I have at the moment:

```
outputs= np.array([np.array([do_model(inputs) for  x in xrange(iterations)])
```

What I would like:

```
def run_model(iterations, inputs):
    # generate a 1D array of length iteration containing the input array
    my_array = np.full((1,int(iterations)), inputs)

outputs = run_model(iterations, inputs)
# run my function on the array
return do_model(empty)
```

At the moment I get the following error when I try to create `my_array` for 5 iterations:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (1,5)
```

I tried to specify that the array should be filled by another array using the `dtype` keyword argument as such:

```
my_array = np.full((1,int(iterations)), inputs,dtype=np.ndarray
)
```

put that didn't work.

Any help welcome,

The reason I'm asking is I try to run the code on millions of iterations and at the moment I have a memory error.

Comment: "but I was suggested that I could increase my number of iterations if I was to create a function that would make a 1D array of a length equal to the number of iterations I want and then apply my function to this array." Well, frankly, that doesn't sound like a good idea. It sounds like it would be a waste memory-wise as well as running slowly, unless there is a `ufunc` that does the work for you or you plan on writing your own `ufunc`.